# NLTK - How to use NER

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

How can I invoke **NER** from **NLTK** to get all of its results on the first two hundred characters of each of all the **TXT** files located in the same directory?

---

When I try this code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(ebooksFolder):
    fname, fextension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if (fextension == '.txt'):
            newName = 'ner_' + filename
            file = open(ebooksFolder + '\\' + filename)
            rawFile = file.read()
            partToUse = rawFile[:50]
            segmentedSentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(partToUse)
            tokenizedSentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in segmentedSentences]
            posTaggedSentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in tokenizedSentences]
            nerResult = nltk.ne_chunk(posTaggedSentences)
            pathToCopy = 'C:\\Users\\Felipe\\Desktop\\books_txt\\'
            nameToSave = os.path.join(pathToCopy, newName + '.txt')
            newFile = open(nameToSave, 'w')
            newFile.write(nerResult)
            newFile.close()
```

I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 11, in <module>
    nerResult = nltk.ne_chunk(posTaggedSentences)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 177, in ne_chunk
    return chunker.parse(tagged_tokens)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 116, in parse
    tagged = self._tagger.tag(tokens)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 58, in tag
    tags.append(self.tag_one(tokens, i, tags))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 78, in tag_one
    tag = tagger.choose_tag(tokens, index, history)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 554, in choose_tag
    featureset = self.feature_detector(tokens, index, history)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 605, in feature_detector
    return self._feature_detector(tokens, index, history)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 49, in _feature_detector
    pos = simplify_pos(tokens[index][1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 178, in simplify_pos
    if s.startswith('V'): return "V"
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: If someone could recommend a good tutorial about NLTK's NER and POS-tagging, it would be great.

Comment: Show some code for what you have done so far and we'll see how we can help

Comment: @Spaceghost Please, see the code and the errors I added to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having tokenized the text to sentences and then to POS tags, you need to iterate over the list of tagged sentences like so:

```
nerResult = [nltk.ne_chunk(pts) for pts in posTaggedSentences]
```

instead of like so:

```
nerResult = nltk.ne_chunk(posTaggedSentences)
```

Comment: That is an especially helpful clarification because [Natural Language Processing with Python](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) gives the latter as the way to do it and you end up with the above error.